# How to add these two values together in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm really stuck adding these values together.  They both come from a .plist.  Both are numbers. I want to add the values together and display the result as a string in a label.

```
NSInteger calories = [[self.Main objectForKey:@"calories"] integerValue];
NSInteger calories2 = [[self.apps objectForKey:@"calories"] integerValue];
```

I want to basically go with

```
NSString *totalCalories = calories + calories2;
self.calorieLabel.text = totalCalories;
```

But that does not work. I'm new to this and feel like I'm missing something small and obvious.

Any insight?

Answer (score 3):

You’re already there as far as the addition itself:

```
NSInteger totalCalories = calories + calories2;
```

Now you need to convert this number to a string, which you can do like this:

```
NSString *totalCaloriesText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", totalCalories];
```

The problem was that you were trying to treat an integer expression (`calories + calories2`) as a string. This is a valid thing to do in some programming languages, but in Objective-C you have to be explicit about such conversions.

Answer (score 0):

Adding two numbers return numbers, so you'll need to convert your number to NSString, for that you need NSString's stringWithFormat method :

```
NSString *totalCalories = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (calories + calories2)];
self.calorieLabel.text = totalCalories;
```

Answer (score 0):

juste create a string based on the result.

```
NSString *totalCalories = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", calories + calories];
```

Answer (score 0):

@bdesham is right, you can not directly add strings for mathematical operations like add/subtract. Yes some languages do support these kind of operations for strings.

In Objective C, you need to do conversation to specific type before do so. **Above all answers will gives you correct result. Here i provide you to obvious way to do that conversation for number operations**.

```
    NSNumber *caloriesValue = [self.Main objectForKey:@"calories"];
    NSNumber *caloriesValue2 = [self.apps objectForKey:@"calories"];

    NSInteger totalCalories = [caloriesValue integerValue] + [caloriesValue2 integerValue];
    NSString *totalCaloriesText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", totalCalories];
```